# How to add white space to columns with openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to create test data that contains additional white space in the cells. However, it appears that openpyxl strips the whitespace.

How can I deliberately add whitespace into a cell?

The following code shows that whitespace is ignored:

```
import openpyxl 

data = ''' foo ,bar , baz
a, b, c
 d, e, f
 g , h , i '''

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.create_sheet('FIRST', 0)
for row in data.split('\n'):
    sheet.append(row.split(','))

workbook.save(r'C:/openpyxl_whitespace.xlsx')
```

Comment: Are you sure? Can you try opening the sheet and doing some `=LEN(...)` formulas... seems okay to me...?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(row.split(...)`